# Do I need to / should I enable “Virtualization Technology” for Hyper-V in Server 2012?

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012, bios

I'm setting up some new servers to be Hyper-V hosts in Server 2012. I noticed on first boot that the task manager shows the following in the CPU section:

[image]

If I enable "Virtualization Technology" in BIOS, it changes to this:

[image]

This confuses me, as now "Hyper-V support" is gone. I'm almost certain I should be enabling the "Virtualization Technology" option, but why does "Hyper-V support" disappear? Was it just telling me "Your hardware supports Hyper-V, but you can't use it until you turn on Virtualization"?

Comment: What server is that?!

Comment: It's a Dell PowerEdge R510.

Comment: I don't know what the Hyper-V support line means in Task Manager but I can tell you that on my Dell PE R620 servers I have Virtualization Technology enabled in the BIOS, I have Windows Server 2012 with the Hyper-V role installed and am running a number of virtual machines and my Task Manager looks just like your second screen shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not matter. You want the virtualization extensions enabled in your BIOS if you intend to use the server as a hypervisor.

Perhaps the "Hyper-V support" is displaying a capability that's not available under those settings. It's probably linked to the "Virtualization" flag. But since you *need* the virtualization BIOS extensions to be enabled in to accomplish your goal anyway... I don't see the problem. Turn it on and keep moving forward.

Comment: Vote++.  Enabling virtualisation technology (e.g.: Intel VT / AMD-V) extends the instruction set of the processor allowing the hypervisor to perform on-chip virtualisation operations.